# issue with Table Name 'Invalid object name'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In Database,I have Table and Name of Table is **ED-test A_S$Contact** and when i copy & past the name in to class I got some errors which is you can not use '-' or '$' and than i changed name of class to **ED_test_A_S_Contact** and than all errors gone ,but i got another problem ,when i run the project i get this error: `Invalid object name 'dbo.ED_test_A_S_Contact'.` and than i workedaround error: changed the name of DbSet , Mapping , web.config and use `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`,but none of them worked. Can anyone direct me in the right direction? thx

Answer (score 1):

You can revert the table name and use following

```
      modelBuilder.Entity<ED_test_A_S_Contact>().ToTable("ED-test A_S$Contact");
```

Comment: i tried dat before , but i got another problem 'invalid column name ' because in table i have column with this name [Search Name] but, in my class i called public string Search_Name { get; set; } and than i tried this for set property, Property(t => t.Search_Name).HasColumnName("[Search Name]"); , but its not worked and than i changed it to Property(t => t.Search_Name).HasColumnName("Search_Name"); and same history not worked

Comment: @ManDown *"... but I got another problem...*" This doesn't change the fact that the above answer is solving the table name issue described in your current post (question). Another problem requires another post (question). Anyway, I'll give you a hint - don't use `[` and `]` in table/column name mapping methods, e.g. `Property(t => t.Search_Name).HasColumnName("Search Name");`

Comment: god bless you Ivan , after spend so much time ,its works . tnx for help :) if u write as answer and then i will marked as correct answer :)

Comment: @IvanStoev just have Quick question i have column with this name E-mail  (MailIT) , should i remove the Parentheses when i set property or not !

Comment: @ManDown Name your classes and properties using a valid C# names. Use that names when you set/get properties of the class. Use Data Annotations/Fluent config to map them to the database table/column names.

Comment: @IvanStoev, yeah i know , i just wanna know should i write like this Property(t => t.E_mail_Salg__MailIT_).HasColumnName("E-mail Salg (MailIT)"); or like this Property(t => t.E_mail_Salg__MailIT_).HasColumnName("E-mail Salg MailIT");

Comment: Write the column name exactly as it is in the database - **without** enclosing it with `[` and `]`. In your example, `Property(t => t.E_mail_Salg__MailIT_).HasColumnName("E-mail Salg (MailIT)");`

Comment: Tnx again Ivan :-)

Comment: @IvanStoev can i tagging you to one of my question i asked is about property but this time is difficult :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because table names don't simply change just by renaming it. Sounds confusing, I know. Basically, there is the possibility that your table is being referenced to by another database object (table, etc.) which is why the renaming doesn't work the way you want it to.

If you have no important data yet then I suggest scrapping your database and building it again (Easy with code-first migration). Otherwise, you could use tools for renaming tables such as [SQL Prompt](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/index) with the feature [Smart Rename](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SP7/Renaming+objects).

> SQL Prompt can create a script that allows you to rename objects in your database without breaking dependencies.

Comment: yeah you right , i just renaming table in my project and not in Database 
 and its beacuse i cant , if i do dat , we gonna lose to many info and data

Comment: @ManDown I suggest try using database-first approach to create your data context and see what name EF will assign to `ED-test A_S$Contact`. Then use that on your entity and delete the auto-generated context created by database-first approach.

Comment: i did it same thing, but in another way , i used visual studio lightswitch for better overview of my tables and columns and names  and i just copy & past names from LS to my project beside dat , its not my database or i did not build the database , im working on project for company , and its their database